# Kendo Mobile ListView in ASP MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-mobile

I am having a terrible time getting the ListView to do anything.  I followed Telerik's instructions and added the reference and all needed scripts.  I only ever get "[Object object] has no method kendoListView".

After messing around for an hour, I removed the mobile versions of the scripts and instead added the desktop versions.  Now I get "Cannot read property 'aspnetmvc-ajax' of undefined".

I am using Asp.Net with MVC4 and Rayzor.  JQuery is 1.9.1 and Telerik's components are Q1 2013.  Does anyone have any ideas what these errors mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For kendo mobile listview to work, you must use the initialize method of `kendoMobileListView`, not `kendoListView`.  However, you can make your work even easier; if you add a `data-role="listview"` to the element representing the listview, and put a single call of the following in your page:

```
var app = new kendo.mobile.Application(document.body);
```

This initializes all of the widgets for you, by looking for the data-role attribute.  Check this out in [the demos](http://demos.kendoui.com/mobile/listview/index.html#/).

Comment: Thanks. I am initializing this in the cshtml file like "@(Html.Kendo().ListView<....." There is no method for MobileListView. I did find that if I added "all" js file, I am able to get the web version to initialize.  So I am thinking they are missing a dependency in their documentation as using the minimums listed does not work. Still no luck with the mobile version though.

Comment: Oh, OK, so yes, the all version would get you there.  However, I think the issue here is that the MVC wrappers may not work in mobile, because the idea is that you may develop a mobile app using PhoneGap, and thus the mvc wrappers would do you no good.  Not 100% sure though.

Comment: OK, thanks. I'll attempt to use the web version, or maybe a jQuery mobile list instead.